# WordPress Twenty Twelve Responsive Image - Side by Side

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, themes, image-scaling

If you have 2 images side by side in a post, and you minimize the screen you will see that the image on the right gets pushed down below and then then both images start decreasing in size if the screen gets smaller. I am wondering if it is possible to prevent it from dropping down and have it stay side by side and decrease in size at the same time.

You can see an example on this page http://www.glamourgoddessfashion.com/alice-bossman-fallwinter-2013-14/ and around the middle of the post. You will see 2 images side by side, and when you minimize your screen you will see the image get pushed down.

I tried messing around in the CSS but couldn't figure it out. If anyone has any tips that would be great

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple way to do that. Use short code to put each image in it's own column, then put the columns side by side. Each image will now resize AND stay on the same line!